UVDesk v1.1.3 Mailparse error on Ubuntu 24.04 undefined symbol: mbfl_name2no_encoding
I am trying to install UVDesk v1.1.3 for the first time. I spun up a server on AWS with 4GB RAM.
My PHP version is 8.3.
I used composer to install the skeleton from GitHub. After configuring the web service and running the installer. I get the error that PHP mailparse extension is out working.
When I go to the command line and run this command.
 composer update 

The error message is this:
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mailparse.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20230831/mailparse.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/mailparse.so: undefined symbol: mbfl_name2no_encoding), /usr/lib/php/20230831/mailparse.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20230831/mailparse.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I uncommented the mbstring line in the php.ini file and added the mailparse extension to the ini file as well.
I changed the priority in the mailparse.ini file to make sure the mailparse loads after the mbstring. No change.
When I run this command:
  php -m | grep -E 'mbstring|mailparse'

The same error message occurs.
The error is obvious.
/usr/lib/php/20230831/mailparse.so.so:

This file does not exist. PHP is looking for the wrong file. Is this a bug in PHP? Do I need to start over and downgrade to a lower PHP version and mailparse version to get the program to work?
Thank you

This was a great question but what I learned was that I do need to downgrade everything! The system is not made to work on Ubuntu 24.04 nor PHP 8. Found installation instructions here https://support.uvdesk.com/en/blog/prerequisites-ubuntu. 5 hours of my life I have lost!
